# For loop inside While loop print same item

Tags: php, sql-server, json, loops

Maybe is a stupid question BUT I really stuck over here..

Can someone help me understand how to make my for loop works properlly inside a while loop?

For example, I have 2 databases. With while loop I want to display the Id to create a url.

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt)){
    $id = $row['id']; 

    $string = file_get_contents("https://www.url.co.uk/".$id.".json?app_id=b&token=6");
    $arr = json_decode($string, true);
```

That working perfect. Now I am trying inside that loop to insert the data from each URL to new table like that

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
$query = "INSERT INTO TABLE( title, id )"; 
$query .= "VALUES( '{$title}', '{$id}' )";

 $dataatodb = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);  
 if(!$dataatodb){
     die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
 }
}
```

I am trying to achieve for every URL insert to new table the data.

e.g

```
www.url.co.uk/id1.json?app_id=1&token=1 INSERT id,title

www.url.co.uk/id2.json?app_id=1&token=1 INSERT id,title

www.url.co.uk/id3.json?app_id=1&token=1 INSERT id,title
```

But instead of this I get like 10 times each item

Here is

```
$query = "SELECT [id] FROM [Cruise].[dbo].[suppliers]";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $query);

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt)){
    $id = $row['id']; 

    $string = file_get_contents("https://www.widgety.co.uk/api/operators/".$id.".json?app_id=b92d3957926f289200aa89baf2b6f3a2f7156486&token=6ef0dcc476d87160f2ec05d86132ff5e4f40fd66b668e736f3eac6b2fbcd7510");
    $arr = json_decode($string, true);

    for ($i = 0; $i < 108; $i++) {
       $title = $arr['title'];
       $id    = $arr['id'];


       $query = "INSERT INTO TABLE( title, id )"; 
       $query .= "VALUES( '{$title}', '{$id}' )";

       $dataatodb = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);  
       if(!$dataatodb){
          die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
       }//if
    }//for
}//while
```

Comment: what is the for loop for anyway? You don't iterate over anything, you don't use $i anywhere, ..?? How should the outcome be something different than 108 times the same?

Comment: The for loop for the URLs are created with while to run for every one seperate.. Should i have done something else? I am kinda newbie

Comment: I suppose there are several urls in the returned json/$arr and you want to iterate over that. Can you show one record of that json or one record of `print_r($arr)`?

Comment: yes I am able. I want my loop be 108 times Once for every seperate URL and do that query to insert the data in new table. But I get 108 times for 1 URL instead of 1 time for 1st URL,1 time for 2nd ,1 time for 3rd ..........